# Centos8, Phpmyadmin, gateway timeout, importing files

Tags: apache, phpmyadmin, centos8

I have a new Centos 8  server on vultr with phpmyadmin:

```
 Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Tipo di server: MariaDB
Connessione Server: SSL inattivo
Versione del server: 10.3.17-MariaDB - MariaDB Server
Versione protocollo: 10 

     Apache/2.4.37 (centos) OpenSSL/1.1.1c
    Versione del client del database: libmysql - mysqlnd 7.4.3
    Estensione PHP: mysqli curl mbstring
    Versione PHP: 7.4.3

Informazioni sulla versione: 4.9.2, versione stabile piú recente: 4.9.4
```

Any file I try to import, even small (5Mb), .zip or .sql, end up in:

> ```
> Gateway Timeout
>
> The gateway did not receive a timely response from the upstream server or application.
> ```

I also tried to set the upload and timeout times to 10 minutes and the upload size to 512Mbs on php.ini, but nothing has changed.

I can load the .sql files with this from the terminal without problems

```
mysql -u username -p database < /var/www/html/sql_file.sql
```

But what can I do to understand what is not working in phpmyadmin and to make imports into phpmyadmin work?

----------------------update--------------

I try to upgrade to phpmyadmin 5.0.1, no change, and 2 new errors: "$cfg[‘TempDir’] (./tmp/) is not accessible" and "need a blowfish_secret"

Comment: There are multiple configurations which can get you to Gateway timeout, please check this if you have all the settings correct for these parameters based on your original question. https://www.h3xed.com/web-development/php-and-apache-504-gateway-timeout-troubleshooting-and-solutions